# Remedy - BMC - Excluding Users with Last Modified By

Tags: remedy

I am trying to build a search string in Remedy,

I am looking for all open Orders submitted more than 5 days ago, and in which the last updater is not one of the 8 members of our team.

I have the below (and yes, I know it's clumsy, I am a beginner)

```
(('Status*' = "Assigned") OR ('Status*' = "Pending") OR ('Status*' = "Waiting Approval") OR ('Status*' = "Planning") OR ('Status*' = "In Progress")) AND ('Submit Date' <= ($\TIMESTAMP$ - (112 * (60 * 60)))) AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 1") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 2") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 3") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 4") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 5") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 6") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 7") AND ('Last Modified By' != "User 8")
```

I would appreciate if someone could take the time to give me a hand.

Comment: Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

the qualification for the date is in seconds, so you need to tell "current time minus 5 days".

('last submit date' < ( $TIMESTAMP$ - 5 * 24 * 24 * 60)) AND ('Status' < "Closed") AND ('last updated by' <> "team1" ) AND ('last updated by' <> "team2" ) AND ... till team8

Comment: pinging @daniel-pereira (such qualification string used to work fine for me)

Comment: My apologies for the late reply, I couldn't remember my account.

Your string did not solve it as apparently my system works in seconds.

I am not able to use the <Closed either since I have more than 1 different closed status.

I made a few changes, instead of "user" I am using "user ID" and it works.

Thanks for the input either way, it was what made me think I was near the solution.

Comment: Great! Indeed, I forgot a "* 60" on my qualification, that's what happens when "coding" on a text editor ;-)